# django-imagekit tutorial fail - not creating thumbnails

Tags: django, django-imagekit

I've tried according to [this tutorial](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-imagekit/blob/develop/README.rst) but failed. I've got everything copied **exactly** as it is in tutorial. The problem is that ImageKit is not creating thumbnails (both display and thumbnail images).

Here is some detail:

```
>>> from myapp.models import Photo
>>> p = Photo.objects.all()[0]
>>> p.original_image.url
'photos/lena.jpg'
>>> p.display.url
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Photo' object has no attribute 'display'
>>> p.thumbnail_image.url
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Photo' object has no attribute 'thumbnail_image'
```

Comment: it turned out that it was a bug in this revision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using PIL to create thumbnails:
http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

Really easy to use, and easy to follow tutorials:
http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm

Comment: I also use PIL and it's quite easy. Image.open('/path/to/image').thumbnail(500, 300), Image.ANTIALIAS)

Comment: except with just PIL there is no cache